# React truncate multi line text by line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-11, mozilla

I need to truncate card title (text) with react.

[image]

I try to use dotdotdot component https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dotdotdot but it doesn't work with simple component.

```
const content = ({title}) => <Dotdotdot clamp={2}><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est rem magni totam quos sapiente aliquid praesentium quae sint illo quas dicta cum illum dolorum quis eveniet, corrupti porro placeat, consequatur reprehenderit aliquam distinctio voluptates voluptate, temporibus omnis. Cum quis tenetur laborum minus accusantium provident eveniet, corrupti, reiciendis aliquam suscipit hic?</p></Dotdotdot>
```

It doesn't work in ie11 and mozilla. 
In `-web-kit` i have `-webkit-line-clamp` but in mozilla and ie it doesn't work.

Do anybody know decision for this task?

Comment: Please include code that demonstrates what you tried.

Comment: I added simple example how I use dotdotdot in question. https://github.com/CezaryDanielNowak/React-dotdotdot/issues/10 you can look this issue. It doesn't work well in ie11 and mozilla .

Comment: Right. Now please create a codepen/jsfiddle/jsbin/whatever so we can mess around with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install [react-text-truncate](https://github.com/ShinyChang/React-Text-Truncate) and use below code to do it

```
<TextTruncate
  line={1}
  text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
  }
/>
```

Or you can visit the [demo page](https://shinychang.net/React-Text-Truncate/)

Comment: Shiny the demo link doesn't work and the demo linked from github is broken.

Comment: This is the correct link to the dema page: http://shinychang.github.io/React-Text-Truncate/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you want that issue to get resolved or asking for other options as well.

But I usually use [react-lines-ellipsis](https://github.com/xiaody/react-lines-ellipsis) for ellipsis.
If you can go with other alternatives then you can check [demo](https://xiaody.github.io/react-lines-ellipsis/) in other broswers as well.

Comment: Hey does this library also support a 'collapse' functionality? What If I want user to be able to collpase content back?

Comment: I don't think it has

Comment: There is a problem with ie11. It doesn't work in ie11

Answer (score 1):

this works for a single line

```
function TruncatedLine({ text }: { text: string }) {
  return (
    <span style={{ position: "relative", display: "block" }}>
      <span style={{ color: "transparent" }}>X</span>
      <span
        style={{
          display: "block",
          position: "absolute",
          overflow: "hidden",
          textOverflow: "ellipsis",
          whiteSpace: "nowrap",
          width: "100%",
          top: 0,
        }}
      >
        {text}
      </span>
    </span>
  );
}
```

the component will automatically adapt to parent width

```
<div style={{width: "50%"}}><TruncatedLine text="very long multiline text"/></div>
```

Comment: The question was about multi lines